# PageSpeed issue "Remove render-blocking JavaScript:" for load-scripts.php in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

We are currently trying to improve our PageSpeed scores but still stuck at 70.
One of the remaining issues is below:

Remove render-blocking JavaScript:
https://www.example.com/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=jquery-core&ver=4.9.8

This is a WordPress-generated source, but I tried hacking it and added "async" to the script reference but it breaks the site, returning JS errors.
Is there any way we can fix this PageSpeed "issue"? Or is this something we should accept as a technical limitation?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably never get a 100/100 score on PageSpeed Insight. You could try adding this function to defer or asynch script files:

```
// Defer load scripts
function defer_scripts( $tag, $handle, $src ) {

// The handles of the enqueued scripts you want to defer
$defer_scripts = array( 
    'NAME_OF_SCRIPT',
    'ANOTHER_SCRIPT',
);

if ( in_array( $handle, $defer_scripts ) ) {
    return '<script src="' . $src . '" defer="defer" type="text/javascript"></script>' . "\n";
}

return $tag;
} 

add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'defer_scripts', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: I tried that, and I think I also tried a similar approach last time where I added the "async" tag or attribute to the script, but in effect, it broke the site returning "jQuery not defined" errors.